# pass enum parameter from Ajax Jquery to MVC web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, enums

I need to call a web api, this web api method is accepting two parameter one is enum type and another is int. I need to call this api using Ajax Jquery. How to pass enum paramter.

API Code

```
[HttpGet]  
public HttpResponseMessage GetActivitiesByType(UnifiedActivityType type, int pageNumber)
{     
    var activities = _activityService.GetAllByType(type, pageNumber);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, activities);
}
```

My Ajax Call Code:

```
var jsonData = { 'type': 'Recommendation', pageNumber: 0 };

$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: CharismaSystem.globaldata.RemoteURL_ActivityGetAllByType,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: jsonData,
    headers: { "authorization": token },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('scuess');
    }
});
```

Any Suggestions..

Answer (score 8):

An enum is treated as a 0-based integer, so change:

```
var jsonData = { 'type': 'Recommendation', pageNumber: 0 };
```

To this:

```
var jsonData = { 'type': 0, pageNumber: 0 };
```

The client needs to know the index numbers. You could hard code them, or send them down in the page using @Html.Raw(...), or make them available in another ajax call.

Comment: It didn't worked for me it gave me error "500 Critical Exception".

Comment: In my case, I had to set the parameter as an integer then cast it in the controller `public ActionResult Index(int membershipType) { MembershipType memberType = (MembershipType)membershipType; }`

Answer (score 3):

You can not pass `enum` from client side. Either pass `string` or `int` and on the server side cast that value to `enum`. Something like,

```
 MessagingProperties result;
 string none = "None";
 result = (MessagingProperties)Enum.Parse(typeof(MessagingProperties), none);
```

Or you can do something similar to [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/21/manipulating-action-method-parameters.aspx/)